# Where to connect RX and TX on my Sainsmart UNO?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, bluetooth

I am trying to connect a [Bluesmirf Gold](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12582) on my [Sainsmart UNO](http://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-uno-atmega328p-pu-atmega8u2-microcontroller-for-arduino.html).  I don't know where I should connect the RX and TX on the Sainsmart and I don't have any electronics experience.

On Arduino, that's quite clear: digital pins 0 and 1 are reserved for that. But look at the picture of my Sainsmart, and things are not that clear:

[image: Close up of my Saisnmart UNO]

I tried to connect to D0 and D1 but things don't seem to work. Is it because on this model, I should connect to the pins marked TX 1 and RX 0? If so, which of the three rows (S, U or G?) should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signal, voltage, ground. Signal lines connect to the signal pin. The others are provided for the benefit of integrated modules that take power from the same 3-pin connector. Also, RX usually connects to TX and vice versa.

Comment: "RX usually connects to TX and vice versa" -> good to know!